# Query returns all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I want to know during which month the most purchases were made. The query returns all rows, I want to count the purchases for each month.Can someone please help

```
SELECT COUNT(Inv_Num) AS 'NUM OF PURCHASES', DATENAME(MONTH, [Inv_Date]) AS MONTH  
FROM tblInv_info
WHERE DATENAME(YEAR, [Inv_Date]) BETWEEN '2012' AND '2020'
GROUP BY Inv_Num, Inv_Date
ORDER BY MONTH DESC, COUNT(Inv_Num);
```

Comment: Based on your error `[Inv_Paid]` is a datetime but stored incorrectly as a string. And either its not stored using the default format, or its not stored consistently. You need to give us some sample data in order to assist.

Comment: "The Inv_Paid is in DATE datatype" - thats not possible with the error you are getting - its either varchar or nvarchar.

Comment: Tanks for your input, it was stored in varchar but now when I it change to DATE it not returning desired results, it returns all rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is most likely being caused by bad data in one or more records in the `INV_PAID` column.  While I don't have an exact answer for you, if you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, then `TRY_CONVERT` might be one way to flush out the offending records:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblInv_info
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(datetime, INV_PAID) IS NULL;
```